# Convert symbolic expression to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sympy

I'm trying to convert a symbolic expression to an array in python.

For example, I have this symbolic expression:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
A,B = sp.symbols("A B")
G = 3*A**2*B - 2*A*B + A**2
```

What I want is to convert this to an array looking as follows:

```
[3*A**2*B,-2*A*B,A**2]
```

I know how to do this in Matlab, but I need to do it in Python as well.

What I've tried:
I've converted the symbolic expression to a polynomial, which allowed me to collect the coefficients.

```
C = G.as_poly().coeffs()
```

This gets me halfway there:

```
C = [3,-2,1]
```

But I want to have at least a similar list for all the variables.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`as_ordered_terms`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_ordered_terms) to get an ordered list of all the terms:

```
G.as_ordered_terms()
```

gives

```
[3*A**2*B, A**2, -2*A*B]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`args`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#args) to get all the top-level arguments of the object.

```
G.args
```

This will give a tuple:

```
(A**2, -2*A*B, 3*A**2*B)
```